# more PowerShell to VBScript return code problems

Tags: powershell, vbscript

So, I have isolated the "issue" I am seeing to mandatory parameters. This is the calling VBS I have

```
strCmd = "powershell.exe -noLogo -executionpolicy bypass -file ""C:\TestReturnCode.ps1"" -message:""I'm ALIVE"""
result = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(strCMD, 0, True)
msgBox result
```

And this is the PowerShell

```
param (
    [string][parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$message
)

Write-Host $message
Exit 9
```

What actually gets returned is 0, not 9. But, remove `[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]` and suddenly it works. With the parameter mandatory, I can launch the PS1 with a shortcut and it works when the parameter is provided. It's only when launched via VBScript that it doesn't work as expected. This is in PS2.0, FWIW.
Anyone see something I am doing wrong, or is this a bug I just have to accept? It seems a bit ridiculous that Microsoft's own tools won't talk to each other in a meaningful way, but if that is reality I can't fight it. Just not sure it's reality and time for me to move on. ;)

EDIT: It also seems to be Windows 7 only. It works as expected in Windows 10. Hopefully it's a PS issue and updating to a newer version of PS fixes it in Win7.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue also exists in Server 2012 R2 if you run `powershell -version 2`. Looks to me like a PowerShell v2 bug. Upgrade to v3 and the problem should disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the verification Ansgar. Yes, will be headed home from the cafe to manually update my Win7 VM to PS5 and verify that. Not sure what my workaround will be, for users who don't bother to upgrade PS, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Works on Windows 7 with PowerShell v3 and above.